# Growl before Logout on Primefaces

Tags: java, html, primefaces

i have built a client where u can login, watch up some things and logout. It is all working fine. If u click on the logout button he is logging out directly and sending me back to my login page. This happens directly after the click on the logout button. So i wanted to add about 3 seconds waiting time before the client sends me back to my login page. Additinally i wanted to add a growl popup message, that is saying something like: "You are logging out...".
The problem is, that the client doesnt wait the 3 seconds before sending me back and also doesnt show up the dialog. He is sending me directly back. If i only want to show the dialog onclick, he is doing fine, if i want to wait only 3 seconds before loggin out, he is doing fine and he is waiting. BUT when i combine this two things ( popup and waiting seconds) he doesnt do it and directly sends me back.

```
public void logout() {
    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        try {
            thread.sleep(3000);
            ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext();
            ec.invalidateSession();
            ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/home.xhtml");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showLogoutMessage() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Logout",
            "Sie werden abgemeldet!"));

    logout();
}

<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" life="2000" autoUpdate="true" />
<p:commandButton value="#{navigationBean.abmelden}" ajax="false"
                action="#{navigationBean.showLogoutMessage()}" update="growl"  styleClass="menubutton"
                style="position:relative;top:20px">
            </p:commandButton>
```

Can anybody help me or give me another hint for the another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this way:

1. In commandButton use oncomplete to call javascript function.
2. javascript function call p:remoteCommand after 3 second, and remoteCommand call logout.

Code Change here:

```
public void showLogoutMessage(){
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Logout",
        "Sie werden abgemeldet!"));}

public void logout() {
try {
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    try {
        thread.sleep(3000);
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext();
        ec.invalidateSession();
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/home.xhtml");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

xhtml:

```
<p:growl id="growlmm" showDetail="true" sticky="false" life="2000" autoUpdate="true" />
        <p:commandButton value="test" ajax="true"
                         actionListener="#{templateMB.mm()}" update="growlmm"  styleClass="menubutton"
                         style="position:relative;top:20px"    oncomplete="myLogout();"> 
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:remoteCommand id="rcom3" name="rclogout" process="@this"  action="#{templateMB.goOut()}"/> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myLogout() {
                setTimeout('rclogout();', 3000);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The Growl message is popping up but the client doesnt logoff... Do i need some special tags for the script?

Comment: copy and paste this code in your xhtml, see oncomplete on commandButton, also in showLogoutMessage method do not call logout method.